# How to individually print the values per array in pdf form?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to print the values per array in pdf form since this program hold a lot of array and will never be specific in terms of data.

This is my code: `$this->submissionPSDirectCost` function in model which call all the data in database.

```php
        $ps_data_string = "";
        foreach ($this->submissionPSDirectCost as $ps) {
            $ps_data = [
                "<b>" . (($ps->ps_type == 0) ? "Salary" : "Honoraria") . "</b>",
                "<br>",
                $ps->ps_quantity ,
                $ps->title,
                "at",
                $ps->salary ,
                "/Month x",
                $ps->ps_num_duration,
                $ps->mode_payment,
                "<br>",
            ];
            $ps_data_string .= "<tr><td colspan=\"1\">" . implode(" ", $ps_data) . "</td></tr>";
            
        }

        $ps_amount = " ";
        foreach ($this->submissionPSDirectCost as $ps) {
            $psamount =[
            $ps->amount,
            "<br>",
            ];
            $ps_amount .= "<td colspan=\"1\">" . implode(" ", $psamount) . "</td>";
        }
```

and then this is my html inline code to call the `$ps_data_string`

```
'.$ps_data_string.''.$ps_amount.'
```

[CLICK THIS PICTURE: the amount should be in the column of Total approved budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFgQ1.png)

Comment: This question does not yet contain a [mcve] and should be edited to avoid page closure.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in another answer, creating rows directly inside the loop should serve the purpose. However, if I understood the requirement correctly, you need to (shift `$ps_data`, `$ps_data_string` inside it and) create the row only after concatenating all 13 elements of `$ps_data`

```
foreach ($this->submissionPSDirectCost as $ps) {
  $ps_data = null;
  $ps_data[] = ($ps->ps_type == 0) ? "Salary" : "Honoraria";
  //remaining 12 elements of $ps_data to follow
  $ps_row = implode(" ", $ps_data);
  $ps_data_string .= "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">$ps_row</td></tr>";
}
```

Then you use `<table><?php echo $ps_data_string;?></table>` in your html.

Comment: Hi @romeo1987 thank u for this it works for the row! However, all the data are being printed per loop. it makes the data redundant, how can I avoid it? thanks

Comment: @pal can you edit your question and include some sample data showing current output (using this code) Vs expected output?

Comment: Hi romeo, I've already edited my question

Comment: @pal you have shared a template (instead of sample data) and completely modified your code (that you posted initially). The suggested answer, therefore is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows:

```
($this->submissionPSCost as $ps) {
$ps_data_row = array $ps_data_row = ($ps->ps_type == ) ? "Salary" : "Haria";
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->ps_quantity;
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->title;
$ps_data_row[] = "at";
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->salary;
$ps_data_row[] = "/Month x";
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->ps_num_duration;
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->mode_payment;
$ps_data_row[] = " ";
$ps_data_row[] = " ";
$ps_data_row[] = $ps->amount;
$ps_data[] = '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $ps_data_row).'</td></tr>';
}

$ps_data_string = implode("", $ps_data);
```

Now, each row of data is stored in the `$ps_data_row` array, and then it is imploded with `</td><td>` to create the HTML table row structure. The resulting row is then added to the `$ps_data` array.

Finally, you can use this `$ps_data_string` in your HTML template like this:

```html
>
php echo $ps_data_string; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Khribi, the <table> tags isn't working with me. It doesnt appear all the data gathered